# Mount a disk at different points

Tags: 14.04, mount, filesystem

What if I mount the same disk at two locations using different file systems? Will they just be like hardlinks referring to the same location or would it cause any issues?

ex:

```
# mount -t ext3 /dev/sda7 /home/first
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda7 /home/second
```

Similar question:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2156280

Comment: @Rinzwind Changed now. Can you illustrate `bind` option please.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount Gilles seems to tell it better than I can ;=)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use mount with different options for the 2nd time you mount it.  So that is a no.

This is possible:

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda7 /home/first
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda7 /home/second
```

This is not ...

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda7 /home/first
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda7 /home/second
```

The disk you mount does not magically transform from ext3 to ext4 when you tell mount it is ext3 now and ext4 next. It will error out with a "wrong fs" notice.

If you want you can use the "bind" method to create a mount point with different options ...

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda7 /home/first
bindfs -r /home/first /home/second
```

would have you end up with /home/second that is read-only (and /home/first as writable if mounted as writavle). You can use it remap user ID and groups but it still needs to be the same file system. That is what is used on the partition itself not something you set when you use "mount".

Comment: Is there any error. Can you provide an example?

Comment: what do you mean? you will get an error when trying to use mount a 2nd time and with different options (you can not mount 1 read-only and the 2nd writable for instance. You'll get a "mountpoint is busy" notice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you why so? I can the access the data using `sudo cat /dev/<diskname>`.